# How to log errors once using FileTarget

Tags: php, yii2

I use the Yii component "log" to log some important info. In the targets I have:

```
[
    'class' => FileTarget::class,
    'categories' => ['import.category'],
    'levels' => ['info', 'warning', 'error'],
    'logFile' => '@runtime/logs/import/import.log',
    'maxFileSize' => 10240,
    'logVars' => []
]
```

I call the logger in this way:

```
Yii::warning('some message', 'import.category');
```

I have a record in logs/import/import.log. That is good. But I have the same record in logs/app.log.
I do not need the record in logs/app.log. Is this by default? Can I turn it off?

By the way, if I use:

```
Yii::info('some message', 'import.category');
```

I have a record only in logs/import/import.log, but an error or warning duplicates the record.

Comment: Do you want to exclude `import.category` from `app.log` file? Or are you trying to completely remove logging into `app.log` file?

Comment: Just exclude import.category from app.log file? That means, if I log like this: ```Yii::info('some message', 'import.category');
``` I will log only in import.category, not in app.log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration for your `app.log` target probably looks like this:

```php
[
    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
    'logFile' => '@runtime/logs/app.log',
],
```

Because no categories are specified, all error and warning messages are written there. To exclude category from getting logged in target there is [`$except`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-log-target#$except-detail) property in `yii\log\Target` which is common parent for log targets. So you want to modify your setting for `app.log` target like this:

```php
[
    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
    'logFile' => '@runtime/logs/app.log',
    'except' => ['import.category'],
],
```